# How to override the transition of drawer from antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I have 2 drawers from antd - first calls the second, when I open the first everything is okay, but when I open the second - the first transitions 180px to the right

- transformX(180px)

I've seen that this is an open issue on github - https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/18781

but I've tried the solution one of them wrote and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through styled-components there's a way to override it -

```
import { Drawer } from "antd";
const StyledDrawer = styled(Drawer)`
  .ant-drawer-content-wrapper {
    transform: translateX(0px) !important;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

try set push={false}
like:

```
<Drawer push={false} />
```